# zsh: no such file or directory error even though the file exists

Tags: linux, shell, rhel, zsh

I'm getting an error while executing a binary that the binary cannot be found. I can see it using other commands.

```
>> ls -alh                                                                                                                                                                     
total 1.3M
drwxr-xr-x 3 igor 4.0K Sep 28 15:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 igor 4.0K Sep 28 15:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 igor 4.0K Jun  4 09:24 autocomplete
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor  13K Jun  4 09:24 CHANGELOG.md
-rwxr-xr-x 1 igor 1.2M Jun  4 09:24 hyperfine
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor 9.8K Jun  4 09:24 hyperfine.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor  12K Jun  4 09:24 LICENSE-APACHE
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor 1.1K Jun  4 09:24 LICENSE-MIT
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor 9.8K Jun  4 09:24 README.md
```

but when I run the command, I get the following error:

```
>> ./hyperfine --version
zsh: no such file or directory: ./hyperfine
```

Both commands were run in the same directory, I'm using RHEL8, and tried in bash/zsh with no luck, tried other commands like `cat` and `vi`. They seem to find the binary and open it but the execution fails.

Can anyone please advise what may be the issue here? What am I missing?

Thank you very much

Comment: What does `file ./hyperfine` output? Did you build the binary yourself, or did you copy it over from somewhere?  What architecture are you running on (the output of `uname -m`)?

Comment: Thank you @Kusalananda !  "file" showed that it's ELF 32-bit LSB shared object instead of ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64. I've downloaded the wrong tar. Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one for you get points? 
Thank you again, the 64bit version works fine.

Comment: I don't need to write an answer as there is currently a very good answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you downloaded hyperfine for the wrong architecture, like you're on a GNU/Linux x86_64 system and you downloaded https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine/releases/download/v1.17.0/hyperfine-v1.17.0-i686-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz instead of https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine/releases/download/v1.17.0/hyperfine-v1.17.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz or the other way round.

Then:

```
$ file hyperfine
hyperfine: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=07cbf2d0f0cec091ae460dc287bbacdc9f158849, stripped
$ objdump -s -j .interp hyperfine

hyperfine:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .interp:
 0174 2f6c6962 2f6c642d 6c696e75 782e736f  /lib/ld-linux.so
 0184 2e3200                               .2.
```

You can run i686 executables on a x86_64 system, but here you're missing the 32 bit dynamic linker (and most likely the 32 bit libraries that that software is linked to).

The ENOENT error that `execve()` returns and that zsh translates to `no such file or directory` is about that `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` that can't be found on your system.

While you could install the 32 bit versions of the libc, best would be to get the software for the right architecture.

Comment: I'm just curious if bash tells you anything more relevant under these circumstances

Comment: @Swi  No,  It doesn't. I'm getting the same error on the same file. Unfortunately, the problem is on the OS level, not a shell one.